# Les sens des expressions « Ça m'est égal », « Je m'en fiche », « Je m'en contre fiche », « Je m'en fous »

Tags: sens, expressions

Je me demande les sens des expressions « Ça m'est égal », « Je m'en fiche », « Je m'en contre fiche », « Je m'en fous ».  Je comprends chaque expression comme une méthode d'exprimer "I don't care" en Anglais, mais je sais que chaque expression est différente.

Alors, je voudrais aussi savoir:

- Quelles expressions sont plus fortes et moins fortes ?
- Le niveau de politesse ou impolitesse des expressions.

Comment: Je m'en tape, je m'en balance, qu'importe, rien à cirer, comme tu veux, c'est pareil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le sens est le même, c'est le niveau de langue qui diffère :

- Ça m'est égal : niveau courant.
- Je m'en fiche et je m'en contre fiche (« contre » donne un peu plus d'emphase) :  niveau familier.
- Je m'en fous : niveau très familier, vulgaire.

Autres expressions ayant le même sens :

- Je m'en bats l'oeil : très familier.
- Je m'en tamponne le coquillard : vulgaire.

Answer (score 3):

En complement de la reponse de Laure:

Je m'en tamponne le coquillard "avec une queue de hareng"

Aussi:

Je m'en moque: poli

Je m'en balance: vulgaire

Comment: « Poli » peut-être pas, même si ça reste respectueux.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess that you are from Halifax in Canada, not from Halifax in Ye Olde Yorkshire.

You have sorted in the right order the expressions, from a weak and almost polite to a strong one.

I would, but the context could be very significant and alter my answers :

- "ça m'est égal" = I don't mind, it's the same to me, it's all one (very polite, except perhaps the meaning);
- "je m'en fiche" = I couldn't care less (less polite, by far);
- "je m'en contre-fiche" = I wouldn't give a damn for (beginning to be rude);
- "je m'en fous" = er..., very strong, try to adapt a bl** or a f** word - I won't translate, too dicey.

Comment: Upvoting, because it is the only answer that actually states that "ça m'est égal" is rather "I don't mind" than "I don't care".

Answer (score 2):

Mais *la plus part du temps*

> **Ça m'est égal**

sous entend que l'on est face impérativement à deux (ou plus ) alternatives qui impliquent des conséquences...

Pour les autres on peut être en face d'une seule conséquence...

Answer (score 2):

En complément de la réponse de Laure, une expression pittoresque, du même registre que *I don't give a f~ck* et qui s'emploie curieusement aujourd'hui indifféremment quel que soit le sexe du locuteur est "**Je m'en bat les coui**es.**" évidemment très vulgaire.

Un équivalent plus distingué (souvent attribué à un ancien Président de la République) : "**Ça m'en touche une sans faire bouger l'autre.**"

Answer (score 2):

En très vulgaire tu as :

> « Je m’en branle »

Et en soutenu tu as :

> « Peu importe »