# Comment décortiquer : Je m'en balance, Je m'en bats l'œil, Je m'en tamponne le coquillard ?

Tags: expressions

Je repose cette question sur [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7812/les-sens-des-expressions-ca-mest-egal-je-men-fiche-je-men-contre), d'où je retiens que *je m'en fiche* est un synonyme de : *je m'en balance*, *je m'en bats l’œil*, et *je m'en tamponne le coquillard*. Comment décomposer ces expressions ?

1. **Je m'en balance :** S'il faut balancer de qqch, alors il faut s'en embarrasser. Dès lors, on ne doit pas en ficher !
2. **Je m'en bats l’œil :** S'il faut cligner des yeux/sourciller à qqch (c-à-d y battre l'œil), alors il faut s'en tracasser. C'est l'inverse de « je m'en moque » !
3. **Je m'en tamponne le coquillard :** S'il faut apposer une marque sur le coquillard à cause de qqch, alors il faut s'en faire du bile. Même incohérence !

Comment: Quelle est la question au juste? En quoi est-elle différente de l'autre? Stéphane a été très explicite: la seule et unique différence de sens entre ces expressions est une vulgarité grandissante.

Comment: @Circeus - Peut-être que la question est: Que représente _en_ dans ces expressions?

Comment: La question me semble justifiée : le sens usuel de ces expressions est clair, mais le sens littéral ne l'est pas forcément.

Answer (score 5):

Toutes ces expressions sont des expressions figurées et il serait vain de vouloir les décortiquer pour les prendre à la lettre.
Par ailleurs dans ces expressions 2) et 3) l’œil et le coquillard désigne des orifices : l’œil c'est l'anus, et le coquillard, selon les références, l'anus ([Wikipédia](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_tamponner_le_coquillard)) ou le sexe féminin (*Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*), même si de nos jours ces mots ne sont plus employés avec ce sens là que dans ces expressions.

En l'absence de références plus précises, et dans la mesure où on dit aussi bien « je m'en tape », « je m'en tape l’œil » et « je m'en bats l’œil », battre et taper peuvent être pris dans le même sens, à savoir s'essuyer.
Pour résumer toutes ces expressions veulent dire la même chose : « tout ça m'est tellement indifférent que [je m'en torche le cul](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/torcher) avec. »<sup>1</sup>

Pour ce qui est de balancer, un des sens figuré du mot est : jeter. On peut passer facilement du sens de jeter à celui de se débarrasser de ce qui ne nous intéresse pas. Ce qui ici n'explique pas la présence du *en* au contraire des deux autres expressions. Peut-être par mimétisme d'une expression à l'autre ? Glissement phonétique (me/m'en) ?

---

<sup>1</sup> [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/torcher) Loc. fig. Se torcher le cul/le derrière avec/de qqc., s'en torcher (le derrière, le cul). Faire peu de cas de quelque chose, s'en moquer éperdument.

Comment: A moins qu'il ne s'agit d'être tranquille et heureux sur une balançoire, peu concerné par ce qui arrive. Je pense à "Moi je me balance" la chanson de Barbara au rythme oscillant : "De vos histoires, je m'en balance ..."